# How do I get just the head from gitosis?

Tags: git

I have gitosis running on my server. My build system needs to get a copy of the code from gitosis. Right now I clone the whole repository, which takes a long time.

How do I get just the head of a branch? (I've tried git archive, but can't seem to get an archive from gitosis.)

Can I create an archive from a bare repository?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using git to get just the latest revision](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/using-git-to-get-just-the-latest-revision)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pass the `--depth=1` flag to `git clone` to only get the HEAD commit. This creates a "shallow clone". Note that there are limitations with a shallow clone: you can't get the full history (obviously), you cannot clone or pull from it, and you cannot push from it.

Comment: This works, but if pull doesn't work how to then sync with the main repository without rm and clone again ?

Comment: @Antonello: If you need to keep in sync, you should clone the entire repo.

Answer (score 2):

gitosis does not yet support git-archive, AFAIS. The corresponding branch at http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git;a=commitdiff;h=refs/heads/remote-archive has not been merged.

So you can't use "git archive --remote=git://git.example.com/repo.git ..." with gitosis yet.

Comment: Note that the patch you mention is very easy to apply yourself. I did this on my Ubuntu server and it works like charm. I can `git-archive --remote` all I want now! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just created a test bare repo and yes, you can create an archive from a bare repository.

```
$ cd /tmp/foo.git/
$ git archive --output=/tmp/foo.tgz HEAD
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether remote side **enabled archive support**, you can try:

```
git archive --remote=git://git.example.com/repo.git --output=repo.zip HEAD
```

But you have to be either able to access repository via SSH protocol, or support for this has to be explicitely enabled in [`git daemon`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html), so it is rare.

Comment: How do I enable archive support on the remote side. And why is it rarely enabled, is there some danger with it?

Comment: For access via `git://` protocol, the command line that invokes `git daemon` (in inetd, xindetd, etc.) must contain `--enable=upload-archive`; you can also try to just setup `daemon.uploadarch` to true in **remote repository**

Comment: @ablerman: I don't know if gitosis support `git://` (I think it can configure `git daemon`), but if you have SSH access or repository is on the same filesystem you don't need to enable anything (just checked).