# git: getting current revision only

Tags: git

I'm setting up a script that downloads application source code from remote git repository and then launches the application build process. For obvious reasons I only need the current state (revision) of codebase to be downloaded - no need for history. Is there a way in git to achieve that? Cloning the whole repository is too painful.

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/

Answer (score 17):

You can use `git clone --depth 1 ...` (see [FAQ: How do I do a quick clone without history revisions?](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_do_a_quick_clone_without_history_revisions.3F))

Answer (score 14):

You may try the `--depth=1` parameter of git checkout:

```
git clone --depth=1 git://somehost/somerepo.git
```

alternatively, if your remote host support, you can use `git archive`:

```
 git archive --format=tar --remote=git://somehost/somerepo.git master  | tar -xf -
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a script implies you are going to be building from the same repository repeatedly.  If that's the case, doing a `git clone` with full history is still beneficial, because it only needs to be done *once*.   After that, having the local history will speed up your checkouts considerably even over using `git clone --depth=1`, because you only download the changes.  `git clean` will do the job if you need to get back to a pristine state for building.