# How do I clone a large Git repository on an unreliable connection?

Tags: git, git-clone

I want to clone LibreOffice. From the official website, this is what's written:

> All our source code is hosted in git:
>
> Clone: `$ git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core` # (browse)
>
> Clone (http): `$ git clone http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/libreoffice/core.git` # slower
>
> Tarballs: `http://download.documentfoundation.org/libreoffice/src/`
>
> please find the latest versions (usually near the bottom)

now, when I write this command in git bash to clone, it starts fetching. But the repository is so big that after hours I lose connectivity for a few seconds, it rolls back the download, and I get nothing.

Is there any way I can download the repository smoothly even if interruptions occur?

P.S. I am a new user of Git and I use a 1 MB DSL internet connection. The repository must be over 1 GB.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/using-git-to-get-just-the-latest-revision

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The repository is accessible via the `http` protocol (aka dumb protocol) here: http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/libreoffice/core.git.

You can download everything here with `wget` or another download manager, and you'll have a clone of the repository.  After that, you rename the directory from `core.git` to `.git`, and use the following command to tell git about the remote url:

```
$ git remote add remote http://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/libreoffice/core.git
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Comment: this works for LibreOffice but what if the repo is not hosted anywhere else.

Answer (score 17):

do 'git clone --depth 100'
It should grab the last 100 commits

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful for my case

Comment: `git fetch --unshallow` has been added to `git` since this answer was written

Answer (score 13):

You can do the following:

```
git clone --depth 1 git@github.com:User/Project.git .
git fetch --unshallow
```

The first `clone` will still be atomic, so if your connection is not reliable enough to fetch the current HEAD then you will have trouble.

The subsequent `fetch` should be incremental and retryable if the connection drops half-way though.

Answer (score 11):

Increase buffer size so that git can utilize your bandwidth properly. Use following commands.

```
git config --global core.compression 0

git config --global http.postBuffer 1048576000

git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 100M

git clone <repo url>
```

Wait till clone get complete.

Comment: Why this is not the accepted answer. This solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The best method that I know of is to combine [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#git-clone---depthltdepthgt) (`--depth 1`) feature with [sparse checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-read-tree#_sparse_checkout), that is checking out only the subfolders or files that you need. (Shallow cloning also implies `--single-branch`, which is also useful.) See [udondan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28039894/5407270) for an example.

Additionally, I use a bash loop to keep retrying until finished successfully. Like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

git init <repo_dir>
cd <repo_dir>
git remote add origin <repo_url>

# Optional step: sparse checkout
git config core.sparsecheckout true                     # <-- enable sparse checkout
echo "subdirectory/*" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout      # <-- specify files you need

# Keep pulling until successful
until $( git pull --depth=1 origin master ); do         # <-- shallow clone
    echo "Pulling git repository failed; retrying..."
done
```

In this way I can eventually pull large repos even with slow VPN in China…

Importantly, by pulling this way you will still be able to push.

Answer (score 2):

I used a my web hosting server with shell access to clone it first and then used rsync to copy it locally. rsync would copy only remaining files when resumed.

Comment: in shared hosting the shell access is not given.