I can't fork a big github repository using git
So basically I'm trying to clone the Zen Browser Desktop github repository to contribute to it, but I guess because it's too big I can't clone it.
I tried to clone in the normal way, and I got the error:
PS C:\Users\tom\OneDrive\Programming\Zen Browser> git clone https://github.com/zen-browser/desktop.git
Cloning into 'desktop'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 22835, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (450/450), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (186/186), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 92 HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly: CANCEL (err 8)
error: 7254 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

I then looked at other stack overflow forums, and each time I tried a solution the "curl 92" came down:
PS C:\Users\tom\OneDrive\Programming\Zen Browser> git clone https://github.com/zen-browser/desktop.git
Cloning into 'desktop'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 22835, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (454/454), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (186/186), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 0
error: 5095 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

PS C:\Users\ulyss\OneDrive\Programming\Zen Browser> git init
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/ulyss/OneDrive/Programming/Zen Browser/.git/

PS C:\Users\tom\OneDrive\Programming\Zen Browser> git config http.postBuffer 524288000

PS C:\Users\tom\OneDrive\Programming\Zen Browser> git clone https://github.com/zen-browser/desktop.git
Cloning into 'desktop'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 22835, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (454/454), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (186/186), done.
error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 3100 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

In the end, it gets stuck at "curl 18".
In short, I've looked everywhere, and I can't find a solution that suits me personally.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317479/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891229/7976758 . Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+big+repository

BTW it's not forking, it's cloning. A fork is a copy of a GitHub repository in your GitHub namespace.

Yeah, for forking its a translation problem, I didn't meant it like that. Also, thanks a lot! It finally worked for me.
The only comment I forgot to test was the right one lol.
I'm not sure how can I mark your answer as good

"how can I mark your answer as good" You cannot as it were not answers, only comments. Which one did help?

the first link helped me
