Error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining After receiving 1.00GB it got stuck and throws the error
After receiving 1.00GB it got stuck and throws the error:
Receiving objects:   0% (100/11910), 1.00 GiB | error: RPC failed; curl 18 transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
error: 3778 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317479/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891229/7976758 . Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+big+repository

tried all but not working for me

whats your postBuffer size set to?

postBuffer = 524288000
