# Download Git repo without all the .git stuff?

Tags: git, github

Is there a way to download the contents of a git repo from the Unix command line that doesn't pull down everything in the .git directory?  I just want the latest version of the repo directories and files, not all the diffs.

Also, is it possible to accomplish this without using a git command (perhaps with wget or curl, for example)?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible with a `git` command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/using-git-to-get-just-the-latest-revision. 
I don't know what the git internal structure is, but I seriously doubt wget or curl would be useful.

Comment: What do you count as "the contents of a git repo"? The commit history that leads to the current version is part of this being a repository. Downloading the latest version is like downloading the latest release ZIP: No history, just the files. If there is no release, `git archive` should help, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160608/how-to-do-a-git-export-like-svn-export

Comment: @random: I really hate it when people get trigger happy with rejecting questions that would help so many people. Yes it's a perfectly valid question. Programming in the real world is more than just typing a+b

Answer (score 26):

github has a link to download a .zip archive of the repo, so try using

```
wget https://github.com/[user]/[repo]/archive/[branch].zip
```

with `[user]`, `[repo]`, and `[branch]` replaced with the appropriate fields.

Comment: Through the API, you could get a tarball instead of a zipball as well.  [article](https://help.github.com/articles/downloading-files-from-the-command-line) [API reference](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-archive-link)

Comment: @Charlie Very true, but the OP asked for a solution with `wget` so that's what I gave them.

Answer (score 10):

As far as I know, the closest thing you can do is to do a `git clone --depth=1` (to avoid retrieving more information from the server than you need for the latest version) and then delete the `.git` directory afterwards. As far as git is concerned, the `.git` directory *is* the repo; the checked-out files are just there for your convenience. :)

Comment: couldn't you use the git protocol directly to clone stuff without downloading the .git thing in the first place??

Answer (score 2):

2nd part : You can try the username and repo name substituted correctly

```
wget http://github.com/[username]/[repo]/archive/master.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays* github even supports direct `tar.gz` download.

Therefore the following works nicely

```
curl -L http://github.com/[username]/[repo]/archive/[branch].tar.gz | tar zxf -
```

Note, the `-L` option in `curl` is important since that URL has a lot of `302 Redirect` HTTP replies before giving out the content. `wget` automatically follows them, whereas `curl` does not.

[*] 7 years later ;-)