# How can I transfer only the latest repo change files in git?

Tags: git

My git repo is stored on TFS with no remote access to it via the internet. I need to copy changes from this repo to a webserver. I can access this server manually.

I'd like to copy the changes to the repo on the webserver so I can use a git client  to manage pulling and viewing changes.

How can I copy just the latest change files without copying the whole repo? Is it just a case of copying the latest folders in the `./git/objects` folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using git to get just the latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/using-git-to-get-just-the-latest-revision)

Comment: Generally either A) it's not worth the trouble, copy the whole repo or B) the repo history has become bloated from storing very large files in which case use [git-lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/) to slim it down.