# how do you download your repo as a file directory

Tags: git, git-archive

I am trying to download a private git repo.

when I do `git clone https://<DEV_USER>:<DEV_PWD>@github.<corpName>.net/Svcs/repo.git`

it works!

But I dont really need all the git history. I just need the repo as a file directory. Hence I was trying to archive.

`git archive --remote=<DEV_USR>:<DEV_PWD>@github.<corpName>.net:Svcs/repo.git`

I get the following error

```
Could not resolve hostname <DEV_USER>: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using git to get just the latest revision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209999/using-git-to-get-just-the-latest-revision)

Comment: I did refer the post but it basically talks about getting minimal git history, I basically want no git history tied to the repo. Just plain ol' file directory.

Comment: @Gayatri https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive#git-archive---remoteltrepogt: the argument should be one shown in https://git-scm.com/docs/git-upload-archive

Answer (score 0):

The URL is incorrect:

- if you use an SSH one, you would not use your GitHub Enterprise login pasword, but `git@github.<corpName>.net:Svcs/repo.git` (and your SSH keys would be enough to authenticate you)
- if you use your credentials (login/password `<DEV_USR>:<DEV_PWD>`) then use an HTTPS URL `https://<DEV_USR>:<DEV_PWD>@github.<corpName>.net/Svcs/repo.git`

Comment: Thanks. but on https call I get an error `fatal: Operation not supported by protocol.`